# How to get text output from a web service onto a text view

Tags: android, mobile, textview

I have a mobile app that searches for a definition that connects to a web service. The current output comes in the form of a toast pop up but I would like it to appear in the text view to make it look better and more readable.

```
public class Definition extends Activity {

Button btnSend, btnSaveFave, btnReturn;
EditText enterDefinition;
//String wordRecieved;


private InputStream OpenHttpConnection(String urlString) 
        throws IOException
        {
            InputStream in = null;
            int response = -1;

            URL url = new URL(urlString); 
            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

            if (!(conn instanceof HttpURLConnection))                     
                throw new IOException("Not an HTTP connection");        
            try{
                HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) conn;
                httpConn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
                httpConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
                httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
                httpConn.connect();
                response = httpConn.getResponseCode();                 
                if (response == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                    in = httpConn.getInputStream();                                 
                }                     
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.d("Networking", ex.getLocalizedMessage());
                throw new IOException("Error connecting");
            }
            return in;     
        }

private String WordDefinition(String word) { 
InputStream in = null;
String strDefinition = "";
//wordRecieved = word;
try {
    in = OpenHttpConnection(
    "http://services.aonaware.com/DictService/DictService.asmx/Define?word=" + word);
    Document doc = null;
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = 
        DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder db;            
    try {
        db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        doc = db.parse(in);
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }            
    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize(); 

    //---retrieve all the <Definition> elements---
    NodeList definitionElements = 
        doc.getElementsByTagName("Definition"); 

    //---iterate through each <Definition> elements---
    for (int i = 0; i < definitionElements.getLength(); i++) { 
        Node itemNode = definitionElements.item(i); 
        if (itemNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) 
        {            
            //---convert the Definition node into an Element---
            Element definitionElement = (Element) itemNode;

            //---get all the <WordDefinition> elements under 
            // the <Definition> element---
            NodeList wordDefinitionElements = 
                (definitionElement).getElementsByTagName(
                "WordDefinition");

            strDefinition = "";
            //---iterate through each <WordDefinition> elements---
            for (int j = 0; j < wordDefinitionElements.getLength(); j++) {                    
                //---convert a <WordDefinition> node into an Element---
                Element wordDefinitionElement = 
                    (Element) wordDefinitionElements.item(j);

                //---get all the child nodes under the 
                // <WordDefinition> element---
                NodeList textNodes = 
                    ((Node) wordDefinitionElement).getChildNodes();

                strDefinition += 
                    ((Node) textNodes.item(0)).getNodeValue() + ". \n";    
            }

        } 
    }
} catch (IOException e1) {
    Log.d("NetworkingActivity", e1.getLocalizedMessage());
}   
//---return the definitions of the word---
return strDefinition;
}

private class AccessWebServiceTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
    return WordDefinition(urls[0]);
}

protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
{
            //I think the this is where the output problem is however im unsure
    //enterDefinition.setText(result);
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}
```

Comment: put a text view in your xml layout file, and take handle of it in your activity and just set the result by using `textview.setText(result);`

Comment: The thing is I cant access 'result' outside the method 'onPostExecute'

Comment: I have post my answer please check

Answer (score 0):

Hope it will help you..

```
          public class Definition extends Activity {
          TextView textView;

          @Overide
          public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.xyz);
          textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.abc);
          }
```

Now Just call `textView.setText(result)` on post Execute it will work.